# Google PubSub - Counting how many messages in Subscription

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

I've looked over the documentation for Google's PubSub, and also tried looking in Google Cloud Monitoring, but couldn't find any means of figuring out how to get the total amount of messages in my subscriptions.

Since I plan on using PubSub to analyze the amount of data that comes in, it's important for me to get a total count of messages in each subscription.

I would love to know if this is a supported feature or if there is a metric that can calculate the amount.

Comment: Did you check metric [subscription/sent_message_count](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub)?

Comment: you have unack message count on the pubsub subscription page

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for taking the time to respond, but isnt unack messages that arent sent to the subscribers?

Comment: Yes, that's all the message not yet delivered and queued in the subscription.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere then this metric would not useful in this case because  I would like to know how many messages are sent to the subscribers rather than the ones that are not sent , no?

Comment: @RiccoD I have not tried this metric actually  I will look into this potential  metric to see if it helps

Comment: Ok, you want the number of attempts? Number of Ack? At the stackdrivers metrics should provide you that information. But you need to add a time window (number of message delivered per minute)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I want to know how many messages are sent to the subscription per 30 minutes  as my end result